# Extra vertical padding around Navigation Bar and Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation, flutter-appbar, flutter-gridview

I'm encountering extra padding around both the navigation bar at the top and the bottom navigation bar in my Flutter application. This padding creates unnecessary space and disrupts the intended visual layout.
[the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP6KX.jpg)

here is the code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf2f2fe),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: appBarBg,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'IT Buzz',
                style: TextStyle(color: appBarTxt),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 7,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.menu_book_outlined,
                color: Color(0xFFf2f2fe),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Color(0xFFFFF6B7),
                // Color(0xFFF6416C),
                // Color(0xff3C8CE7),
                Color(0xff00EAFF),
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
            child: selectedCourse.isEmpty
                ? GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                    ),
                    itemCount: filteredCourses.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final courseName = filteredCourses[index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          navigateToCourses(courseName, index);
                        },
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 5.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: tileColors[index % tileColors.length],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                courseName,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  color: Color(0xFFf2f2fe),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : selectedYear.isNotEmpty
                    ? selectedSemester.isNotEmpty
                        ? GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate:
                                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                            ),
                            itemCount: syllabusData[selectedCourse]![
                                    selectedYear]![selectedSemester]!
                                .length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final subject = syllabusData[selectedCourse]![
                                      selectedYear]![selectedSemester]!
                                  .keys
                                  .toList()[index];
                              final driveLink = syllabusData[selectedCourse]![
                                  selectedYear]![selectedSemester]![subject];

                              return buildSubjectTile(
                                  subject, driveLink!, index);
                            },
                          )
                        : GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate:
                                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                            ),
                            itemCount:
                                syllabusData[selectedCourse]![selectedYear]!
                                    .keys
                                    .length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final semester =
                                  syllabusData[selectedCourse]![selectedYear]!
                                      .keys
                                      .toList()[index];
                              return buildSemesterTile(semester, index);
                            },
                          )
                    : GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                        ),
                        itemCount: syllabusData[selectedCourse]!.keys.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final year = syllabusData[selectedCourse]!
                              .keys
                              .toList()[index];
                          return buildYearTile(year, index);
                        },
                      ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu_book),
              label: 'Syllabus',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.build),
              label: 'Tools',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.language),
              label: 'Websites',
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            // setState(() {
            //   _selectedIndex = index;
            //   if (index == 1) {
            //     Navigator.push(
            //       context,
            //       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CGPAPage()),
            //     );
            //   }
            //   if (index == 0) {
            //     Navigator.push(
            //       context,
            //       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
            //     );
            //   }
            // });
            if (index != 0 &&
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).mounted &&
                !isSnackBarVisible) {
              isSnackBarVisible = true;
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                  .showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Not Implemented Yet'),
                    ),
                  )
                  .closed
                  .then((_) {
                isSnackBarVisible = false;
              });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've tried setting `titleSpacing: 0` within the `AppBar`, but it doesn't seem to be affecting the padding.

Comment: Is this a `ListView` or `GridView` on this screen? My guess is that the extra padding is added by these by default, not the app bar or nav bar.

Comment: Please include the code for the `body` of the `Scaffold`. Pretty sure the padding does not come from any of the two.

Comment: @PeterKoltai yes its a GridView builder like you said can i do something about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Scaffold body, you have a `Padding` widget with the padding set to `EdgeInsets.all(11.0)`. Remember that `EdgeInsets.all` will gives padding to all of the sides, including top and bottom. If you want the padding to be only on the right & left side, use `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 11.0)`.

Keep in mind that `GridView` also has its own padding property, which might be handy if you want the padding to be included as part of the scrollable widget.

Comment: thx by the way that fixed it 
my ui sucks 
but yeah this is enough for a first app ig